# Pass argument and function as argument in python

Tags: python

This code given is a part of my program. Here I want to reduce the 3 functions to just 1 as they are exactly similar except 1 line. I read about passing function(let this function be `Bar`) and its arguments as arguments in another function(let this function be called `Foo` ).

But in this scenario, **I can't change the function `Foo`**. Here my `Foo` function is `.clicked.connect()` and `addXMin` is my function `Bar`. I want to pass `Bar` and its argument `num` into `Foo`, where I can't change whats going on in `Foo`. Is there a way I can reduce the 3 functions into 1 and pass `15`, `10` and `5` as arguments to that single function?

```
self.add15m.clicked.connect(self.add15Min)
self.add10m.clicked.connect(self.add10Min)
self.add5m.clicked.connect(self.add5Min)

def add15Min(self):
    global mins, secs, time
    time = self.lineEdit.text()
    mins = int((time.split(':'))[0])
    mins+=15         #The only different line
    secs = int((time.split(':'))[1])
    time = str(mins).zfill(2) + ":" + str(secs).zfill(2)
    self.lineEdit.setText(time)

def add10Min(self):
    global mins, secs, time
    time = self.lineEdit.text()
    mins = int((time.split(':'))[0])
    mins+=10         #The only different line
    secs = int((time.split(':'))[1])
    time = str(mins).zfill(2) + ":" + str(secs).zfill(2)
    self.lineEdit.setText(time)

def add5Min(self):
    global mins, secs, time
    time = self.lineEdit.text()
    mins = int((time.split(':'))[0])
    secs = int((time.split(':'))[1])
    mins+=5         #The only different line
    time = str(mins).zfill(2) + ":" + str(secs).zfill(2)
    self.lineEdit.setText(time)
```

Comment: yes...also you should not use global...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `connect` accepts single argument, you can use an anonymous function (`lambda` in python) like this:

```
self.add5m.clicked.connect(lambda: self.addMin(5))

def addMin(self, minutes):
    time = self.lineEdit.text()
    mins = int((time.split(':'))[0])
    secs = int((time.split(':'))[1])
    mins += minutes
    time = str(mins).zfill(2) + ":" + str(secs).zfill(2)
    self.lineEdit.setText(time)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a general function and then use `functools.partial` to bind variables to parameters:

```
def addMin(self, mins_to_add):
    global mins, secs, time
    time = self.lineEdit.text()
    mins = int((time.split(':'))[0])
    secs = int((time.split(':'))[1])
    mins+=5         #The only different line
    time = str(mins).zfill(2) + ":" + str(secs).zfill(2)
    self.lineEdit.setText(time)

add5Min, add10Min, add15Min = [functools.partial(self.addMin, x) for x in range(5, 20, 5)]
```

or connect directly:

```
self.add15m.clicked.connect(partial(self.addMin, 5))
```